# Need help echoing out a input button using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to echo out this following input submit button Using php.. .

```
 <input type='submit' value='submit' onClick='parent.location='order_summary.php'>
```

I wrote the following code before but its not working :( 
Can anyone please help me out with this? Thanks!

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' onClick='parent.location="."'order_summary.php'".">";
```

Comment: Are you not getting that output or is the page not working?  You have 3 ' characters for your onClick which will cause a problem.

Comment: Check your quotes.  You can't have single quotes inside single quotes (like in your `onClick`).  `onClick='parent.location='order_summary.php'` is incorrect.  It should be `onClick='parent.location="order_summary.php"'`

Comment: echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" onClick=\"parent.location='order_summary.php'\">"; works for me.

Comment: Rocket Hazamat. Thanks a lot!! That worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about escaping quotes so you don't write broken HTML:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' onClick='parent.location=\"order_summary.php\"'>";
```

or alternatively (since valid HTML uses double quotes):

```
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="parent.location = \'order_summary.php\'">';
```